# Problem with SVD in practice when using Surprise library

Tags: machine-learning, svd

Since SVD decomposition consists of three matrices, U, Sigma, and V Transpose...

https://intoli.com/blog/pca-and-svd/img/svd-matrices.png

Why when I use SVD algorithm for the prediction can access only 2 matrices which are qi and pu:

https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/matrix_factorization.html

Where is the matrix Sigma which contains the singular values?

Comment: What do you need it for? This matrix is not needed for using your inferred knowledge, but plays only a role during computation of the inferred knowledge (in some implementations; and i don't think it's used in this case: it's SGD-based not, SVD-based).Also note this [remark from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_factorization_(recommender_systems)#cite_note-Funkblog-2): `Note that, in Funk MF no singular value decomposition is applied, it is a SVD-like machine learning model [2]`

Comment: Well how can I extract the features I want? In SVD theory I understood that for example I take the first two singular values (out of 3) and if the 3 is low enough, I get almost the same results. How can I do this here now when I don't even have the Sigma matrix. So basically this from Wiki means that the SVD I learned, in theory, is not in Suprise library at all?

Comment: Which features, For which purpose? In MF, from your ratings, which are nonzeros in a matrix of size (m,n), you infer two matrices: U (m, k) and V (k, n). Now these contain your features / latent-vectors, controlled by the size of `k` for example and multiplying them reconstructs the original matrix. The compression-like behaviour of ignoring low-magnitude singular-values, could be seen here as U,V being much smaller as the original matrix (as controlled by `k`). But that's of course no 1:1 mapping. Each user will be described on k features then, each item too.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, the algorithm I used in from Suprise library is not SVD by definition, but an imitation of that algorithm which already does the reduction for me and that then falls under category of MF? Also, I now checked the dimensions of pu (1251 x 250) and qi (8,250) which means that my MF algorithm did the reduction to 8 latent features by himself because he decided that is optimal somehow?

Comment: It's not SVD (but i won't argue about the imitation part). It does learn latent-vectors, some "hidden model" to explain your data, which is based on the low-rank assumption and becomes matrix-factorization. With (1251 x 250), (8,250) the only way to do matrix-multiplication in our MF-model is when k=250 (#left matrix cols = #right matrix row). I'm guessing your data has 1251 users and 8 items or the other way around. But this sounds broken (8 < 250). `250` looks like a classic default for `k` in MF. The author has a [blog](http://nicolas-hug.com/blog/) which somewhat explains SVD vs. Funk-alg

Comment: I have 1251 users and my "8 items" are in fact 8 cluster options I have from doing kmeans clustering before on my data. So you think that my data didn't shrink at all and that k remained default?

Comment: I'm afraid you are doing lots of stuff without carefully thinking about the consequences (maybe take a step back and do more research). Why use low-rank matrix-factorization on a pre-clustered model? There is lots of shared characteristics between clustering and matrix-factorization (so i would not do it twice). `k>min(users, items)` does not make sense to me and i wonder why the lib allows that.

Comment: Well I thought when I'm using Surprise SVD library that that is an actual SVD algorithm, because it is called that way. I'm first time hearing this that it isn't actually SVD. Should I use the k-means clustering and then numpy or scikitlearn's REAL SVD? Because that was my intention from the start

Comment: @sascha Can you help me with this last comment, I really think this is the last thing to clear everything out...

Comment: Sry, cannot help there. I just don't know what you are doing and doing collaborative filtering, as provided by the lib, seems not to be what you are after all (or else you would not drop it for clustering and co.).

Comment: Okay, but do you think it makes sense to use K-means clustering and then regular SVD?

Comment: Can't think of a use-case where this would be a good idea.